# How do I change the default local time format in C++?

Tags: c++, time

I have a function:

```
string get_current_time()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    return asctime (timeinfo);
}
```

which returns time in the following format:

```
Fri Mar 18 11:25:04 2011
```

How do I change it so that it is returned in the following format?

```
2011 03-18 11-25-04 Fri
```

I want to use this for log file names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **@0A0D** suggested, whilst you can't change `asctime`, you can use [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) to format the data contained in your `time_t`:

```
string get_current_time()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    char output[30];
    strftime(output, 30, "%Y %m-%d %H-%M-%S %a", timeinfo);

    return string(output);
}
```

(I've also dropped a copy on to IdeOne [here](http://ideone.com/VLbrj).)

Comment: thx! btw I ended using this with std::stringstream: `ssTime << std::put_time(localtime(&(attr.st_mtime)), "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M");`

Answer (score 3):

`asctime()` always returns in the format Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy . It cannot be changed.

If you want to use a different format, look at [strftime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/).